# Binomial probabilities in a production process

Tags: probability

Screws are made in a production process where the probability of any one screw being defective is constant at p=0.1 i.e. 10% of screws produced are defective.

Screws are placed in bags of 15 at the end of the process. At various intervals a bag is checked and the process is stopped if more than 3 screws in that bag are found to be defective.

I am trying to answer the question "What is the probability that there will be sufficient defective screws to stop the process?".

I am using a sum of binomial probabilities and have calculated the answer to be 0.0555. Does this appear correct? The book I have seen the question in gives a slightly different answer, hence my query here.

Comment: Hello and welcome! What have you tried to solve this problem? Have you perhaps seen a similar problem somewhere? Look in your book.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to solve this problem using binomial probabilities, something I am currently learning about. I wanted to try and check whether I was using the correct technique and whether my calculation was correct. User2566092 helped me with the first part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A somewhat improved way to answer this problem is to ask what is the probability that a bag will NOT stop the process. For this you have a binomial distribution with $p=0.1$, $n=15$ and you want to compute the probability that the number of defective screws is either 0, 1, or 2. (Easy to do, if you know the formula for the binomial distribution). Then 1 minus that is the probability that the bag stops the process. This is easier than computing directly for 3 up to 15 defective screws.

Comment: Yes, but the process only stops if there are MORE than 3 defective screws so I should calculate 1 - Prob(0, 1, 2 or 3 defectives). I get this to be 0.0555.

Comment: sorry i missed that. yes, if you need MORE than 3 defective screws then you want 1 minus the probability of getting 0,1,2, or 3.

Answer (score 1):

Your Parameters for the binomial Distribution are $p=0.1,n=15$. You have to compute the probability that the random variable $X$ denoting "number of screws are defect" has a value greater or equals 3. That means calculate $P(X>2)$ with the binomial Distribution.